# Value Error: could not convert string to float: 'good'

Tags: python, decision-tree, valueerror

I am trying to fit a decision tree model with the training dataset. But finding this error

```
credit_df=pd.read_csv('credit.csv')
credit_df.head()
```

[! [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04z5P.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04z5P.png)

```
X = credit_df.drop("default" , axis=1)
Y=credit_df.pop("default")
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.30, random_state=1)

dt_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'gini' )
dt_model.fit(X_train, train_labels)
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Obviously, your data contains not just numbers, but also strings like "good". You should decide how to replace such strings that they become proper numbers.

Comment: Or turn such colums into ordinal values. There is at least one page, probably more, dedicated to this conversion on the scikit-learn website.

Comment: Yes i tried the below code and the error is fixed now  - for feature in credit_df.columns: 
    if credit_df[feature].dtype == 'object': 
        credit_df[feature] = pd.Categorical(credit_df[feature]).codes

Comment: You can accept your own answer to show your problem has been solved.

Comment: yes, its saying you can accept your own answer after two days only, can you try my code and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code below and now the error is fixed. There were some object data types and i converted them into categorical values

```
for feature in credit_df.columns: 
    if credit_df[feature].dtype == 'object': 
        credit_df[feature] = pd.Categorical(credit_df[feature]).codes
```